# Unable to find valid certification path while posting message

Tags: http, post, https, localhost, x509certificate

I have a server1 running on https://localhost:4040 and another server2 running on http://localhost:5050. When I try to post a request using server 1 to server 2, it shows "**Unable to find certification path to requested target**". Note that the second server is http (not https, and I cannot change that). I tried the solution at https://mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target/ but it does not work (since the other server is on http, it returns with unsupported or unrecognized SSL message). I'll appreciate any help on the issue.

Comment: HTTPS to HTTP connection does not make much sense. If this is for testing purposes, can't you use HTTP on both servers?

Comment: No its a requirement of customer in my company. I did solve the issue though. It seems the https server had its own set of trusted certificates and I had to include the self signed certificate of the http server in the trust-store of the https server.